# Solving a partial differential equation help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, education

this is my differential equation course. I got back into school after a couple of years. This is just the start of this course and I am having difficulties in one of these practice problems.

This is the question:

Find the general form of a function $U(x,y)$ solving the PDE $u_{xx} + yu_x = 0$ (1)

My attempt:

we can write (1) as

(d/dx)(du/dx) + y(du/dx) = 0  $\rightarrow$ (du/dx)[d/dx + y] = 0.

Now from here I am getting confused. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your eq. $u_x (\partial/\partial x + y)=0$ does not all that much sense, unfortunately. Instead of factoring out a $u_x$, try to factor out a derivative $\partial/\partial x$; then, integrate your eq. wrt $x$ & take it form there.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $y$ and name $f(x)=u(x,y)$. Then $f$ satisfies the ODE:
$$
f''+yf'=0
$$
The general solution for this ODE is
$$
f(x)=a+be^{-y\,x}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Therefore the general form for $u(x,y)$ is
$$
u(x,y)=a(y)+b(y)e^{-y\,x}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary functions.